# Minimum record of exponentials getting broken finitely/infinitely many times

Tags: probability-theory, maxima-minima, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

Let us consider the following scenario: we have a sequence $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of independent random variables, where for every integer $n\geq 1$, $X_n$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_n > 0$. Let us define the random variable $m_n = \min \{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ for any integer $n\geq 1$. We need to show that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n = \lambda <\infty$, then, with probability 1, the minimum record gets broken only finitely many times, and if that same $\lambda$ is $\infty$, then, with probability 1, the record gets broken infinitely many times.

**My attempt:**

It is known that $m_n$ is also exponential with parameter $\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n$ (for any positive integer $n$). Thus, one can easily see that $m_n \xrightarrow{d}\text{EXP}(\lambda)$, if $\lambda<\infty$, and $m_n \xrightarrow{d} 0$ if $\lambda=\infty$.

Now, let $N_n$ be the number of times the minimum record is broken up to step $n$, i.e. $$N_n = \sum_{i=2}^n \mathbb{I}_{\{m_i = X_i\}}=\sum_{i=2}^n\mathbb{I}_{\{X_i < m_{i-1}\}},$$
where $\mathbb{I}_E$ is the indicator of an event $E$.

Since $m_i\sim \text{EXP}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^i \lambda_k\right)$, we know that $\mathbb{P}(X_i < m_{i-1}) = \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_i}$, but I don't seem to think these events are independent, and even if they are, I am not sure how to proceed with finding the probability of $N_n$ being bounded when $n\to\infty$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis between binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your work is already in the right direction.

By the (first) [Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) (which doesn’t require independence), the probability of infinitely many records being set is $0$ if the sum of the probabilities of those events is finite. And indeed

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_i\mathbb P(X_i\lt m_{i-1})
&=&
\sum_i\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_i}
\\
&\le&
\sum_i\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}
\\
&=&
\frac\lambda{\lambda_1}
\\
&\lt&
\infty\;.
\end{eqnarray*}
For the other result, we can’t use the second Borel–Cantelli lemma (at least I don’t see how to) because that does require independence. Instead, consider the events $B_n$ that the $X_i$ never go below $\frac1n$. Their probability is $0$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb P(B_n)
&=&
\prod_i\mathbb P\left(X_i\ge\frac1n\right)
\\
&=&
\prod_i\exp\left(-\lambda_i\cdot\frac1n\right)
\\
&=&
\exp\left(-\sum_i\lambda_i\cdot\frac1n\right)
\\
&=&0\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, the probability of the union of these countably many events is also $0$. But the event that there are finitely many records is contained in this union (since the last record is a lower bound on the $X_i$). Thus it also has probability $0$, so the probability for the record to be broken infinitely often is $1$.